# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: waiting for inital communication packet', system error: 138

Tags: mysql

Anyone knows what this error can be?
It happens when I try to connect to an instance.
MySQL is on.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was some heavy SQLs being executed. After solving the SQL problems everything got back to normal.

Comment: Recently I had the same problem again, when trying to connect from outside of the network where the mysql server was. This time the problem was related to the router, it was misconfigured. The mysql port (3306) was correct setted for the external connection, but wasn't correct configured to redirect it to the correct internal port.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your firewall is not blocking anything regarding MySQL. Try to do what you are doing by shutting down your antivirus for 5 minutes. It can simply be your firewall.
To interpret the error you are getting, it simply means that your MySQL client not getting to connect to the MySQL server engine.

Another possibility:
Open your mySQL Client and verify that it si set to use the default port number which is 3306. Another thing to lookup would be the bind-address in my.cnf.  Set it with the following bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in mysql/my.cnf

Comment: I don't have any antivirus, and my firewall is disabled, I discovered that my mysql server is taking 100% of cpu, and when I restart it many times, sometimes it takes lower, when it happens I can connect to mysql normally, do you know what this can be?

Comment: Open your mySQL Client and verify that it si set to use the default port number which is 3306. Another thing to lookup would be the bind-address in my.cnf.  Set it with the following bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in mysql/my.cnf

Comment: I did it but the problem remains :(

Comment: Try to restart the service after flushing privileges

Comment: but to flush privileges doesn't need to connect to mysql first?